# Параметры функций

Tags: c++

Я хочу хочу понять какие параметры нужны в c++ в функции push_heap().Если можете объясните всё простым языком.

Comment: два итератора произвольного доступа и компаратор, если  стандартный компаратор не подходит

Answer (score 2):

На сайте cppreference есть пример - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap

Если кратко - нужно просто два Random итератора на начало и конец контейнера, в котором нужно сделать средующее. Первые элементы - это уже готовый хип, а самый последний элемент - это "вставляемый", который пока не на своем месте. И эта функция поставит его "на место".

Пример, скопированный.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // исходный вектор
    std::vector<int> v { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9 };
    // сделали хип
    std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());

    // распечатали
    std::cout << "v: ";
    for (auto i : v) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    // добавили элемент для "добавления"
    v.push_back(6);

    // снова вывели, что бы показать
    std::cout << "before push_heap: ";
    for (auto i : v) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    // исправили, переместив последний элемент на свое место.
    std::push_heap(v.begin(), v.end());

    // и снова вывели
    std::cout << "after push_heap: ";
    for (auto i : v) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: не просто два итератора на начало и конец контейнера.   А если контейнер не поддерживает  итератор произвольного доступа?.. Например std::list не подходит, его итераторы не могут быть аргументом  для создании кучи